# Python: How to combine a string and a list

Tags: python, regex, list, web-scraping

I am currently trying to connect an URL (String) to a number (list) to form a new URL.
The code looks like this:

```
next_page_number = response.xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-danger"]/@onclick').re('-?\d+')
next_page_number = str(next_page_number)

url = "https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]="

next_page_url= (url + next_page_number)
print (next_page_url)
```

Now, the new `next_page_url` looks like this:

```
https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=['10']
```

Basically, it added the list to the URL. But I don't need the brackets and the quotation marks ['10']. I just need the 10.

How to add the two variables without adding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `next_page_number = str(next_page_number)` with this:

`next_page_number = next_page_number[0]`

This works because next_page_number is a list and `next_page_number[0]` will select the first item of the list which is the string `'10'`. When you did `str(next_page_number)`, you simply make a string representation of the list which will include the brackets.